# Can't yield in forEachAsync inside Stream in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `forEachAsync` inside an `async*` `Stream` and can't `yield`.

```
Stream<ProjectState> _mapProjectSelectedEventToState(ProjectSelected event) async* {
    try {
      yield ProjectLoading(
        message: 'Fetching database',
        fetchedCount: 0,
        totalCount: 1,
      );
      await forEachAsync(fileModels, (FileEntity fileModel) async {
        await downloader.download(filename: fileModel.hashName);
        _totalMediaFilesFetched++;

        //// ERROR - THIS DOES NOT WORK ////
        yield (ProjectLoadingTick(
          _totalMediaFiles,
          _totalMediaFilesFetched,
        ));

      }, maxTasks: 5);
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      yield ProjectFailure(error: error);
    }
  }
```

I've tried other means by dispatching the message and converting it to a state but it doesn't work as well. It seems like the whole app is blocked by this `await forEachAsync`.

I'm using the bloc pattern which reacts to the emited `ProjectStates` based on the current `ProjectSelected event`

Comment: You're making `forEachAsync`'s *callback* `yield` , *not* the function returning a `Stream`.  Why don't you use a normal `await for` loop instead?

Comment: I want parallel downloads... what do you mean by `await for loop`

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt doesn't work because you're using `yield` in a *callback*, not in the function that's returning a `Stream`.  That is, you're attempting the equivalent of:

```dart
Stream<ProjectState> _mapProjectSelectedEventToState(ProjectSelected event) async* {
  ...
  await forEachAsync(fileModels, helperFunction);
  ...
}

Future helperFunction(FileEntity fileModel) async {
  ...
  yield ProjectLoadingTick(...);
}
```

which doesn't make sense.

Since care about [`forEachAsync`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.async/forEachAsync.html)'s ability to set a maximum limit to the number of outstanding asynchronous operations,
you might be better off using a `StreamController` that you can manually add events to:

```dart
var controller = StreamController<ProjectState>();

// Note that this is not `await`ed.
forEachAsync(fileModels, (FileEntity fileModel) async {
    await downloader.download(filename: fileModel.hashName);
    _totalMediaFilesFetched++;

    controller.add(ProjectLoadingTick(
      _totalMediaFiles,
      _totalMediaFilesFetched,
    ));
  },
  maxTasks: 5);
yield* controller.stream;
```